# Difference between $.append() and $.append(document.createTextNode())

Tags: jquery, html, string, append

Using the following html

```
<div id="duo">batman</div>
```

what's the difference between the following two jQuery lines?

```
$('#duo').append(' and robin');

$('#duo').append(document.createTextNode(' and robin'));
```

They both produce

```
<div id="duo">batman and robin</div>
```

Is the first html and the second is merely a string? Does it matter? What are the implications of this and what does the difference mean?

---

**Edit**

What if the text inside the quotes were `' and <em>robin</em>'`? It seems the former statement produces emphasized text, while the latter actually renders visible `<em>` tags on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is the same, the only difference is that jQuery creates the text node in the first line.

If you look at the result using DOM methods (as jQuery works with elements, not nodes), you see the text nodes that are created:

```
$('#duo').append(' and robin');
$('#duo').append(document.createTextNode(' and robin'));

var c = document.getElementById('duo').childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    console.log(c[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
<TextNode textContent="batman">
<TextNode textContent=" and robin">
<TextNode textContent=" and robin">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tgqz37m5/

Comment: I added a second example in the question.

Comment: @pattern86: Yes, in that case there is a difference. jQuery will create the nodes by creating a `div` element and set the `innerHTML` property to the HTML code, then use the child nodes from the `div` in the append. Creating a text node will put the code in the text content of the text node, equivalent of HTML encoding the text and appending it.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and thorough explanation! How does it render the triangular brackets without using &lt; and &gt;?

Comment: @pattern86: The HTML entities like `&lt;` and `&gt;` are only used when you put those characters in HTML code, once the HTML code is parsed they are just the characters `<` and `>`. When you put the text in the text node there is no parsing, you just put that exact text in the node.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference.  In the first case, jQuery is simply taking care of the extra work for you.

Comment: I added a second example in the question.